# ios dst end week and start week is changing on changing region for same time zone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, dst, nscalendar

I am trying to retrieve dst end week and dst start week using .

```
//start week
unsigned char startWOMValue = (unsigned char)[calendar ordinalityOfUnit:NSCalendarUnitWeekOfMonth inUnit:NSCalendarUnitMonth forDate:dstStartDate];

//end week
unsigned char endWOMValue = (unsigned char)[calendar ordinalityOfUnit:NSCalendarUnitWeekOfMonth inUnit:NSCalendarUnitMonth forDate:dstEndDate];
```

I am able to get values. but when I tried to fetch dst end and start week after changing region from my ipad(language and region) and keeping time zone same. it was different.

Time Zone   |Region |Dst start/end week values

Germany, Berlin |USA    |05/05

Germany, Berlin |Germany    |04/04

The upper one holds good but later one is not correct as per current DST in Germany.
I want to achieve method by means of which I can remove dependency of DST from region.

if someone knows about this and how to avoid this.

Comment: What values did you get before and after your change?  What region did you change from/to?  What time zone did you use?  Please edit your question to expand it with these details.

Comment: could be that each region has a different definition of end/start of week

Comment: may be but I am not sure. if it is then there should be some details provided by apple about it.